# multiply all elements of a vector together MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

If I have:

```
vec = 1:10
```

is there a function that will multiply all elements together (1*2*3*4*5...) of it without the need of a for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, did you search the documentation for a function to evaluate the product of a vector or would you like me to do that for you ?

Comment: Please don't forget that not everyone is a native English speaker. The word "product" is different than the word "multiply".

Answer (score 2):

Use the function prod :

```
vec = 1:4;
prod(vec)

ans =

    24
```